# Pandas compute single mean, standard deviation and count on two columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to Pandas.
I would like to compute the mean, standard dev or count on two columns in my dataframe.

Example:

```
A     B     C 
2     NaN   x1
NaN   2     x2
3     3     x3

mean of (A, B)= 2.5
std (A,B) = 0.577
Count (A, B) = 4
```

Can you pls help? The code I see always compute statistics either on one column or across rows.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first create a `Series` out of both columns. Then compute your calculations:

```
s = pd.concat([df.A, df.B])

s.mean()
s.std()
s.count()
```

**Output**

```
2.5
0.5773502691896257
4
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, select your columns and can use `numpy`'s `nanmean` and `nanstd`

```
cols = ['A', 'B']
np.nanmean(df[cols])
np.nanstd(df[cols])
```

For the count, use the `count()` function which already exclude `nan`s

```
df[cols].count().sum()
```

This works because `nanmean` and `nanstd` (like most numpy methods) have `axis=None` as default and just consider all values instead of running against a specific axis.

Bear in mind that `pandas` `std()` use as default 1 degree of freedom, while `numpy` uses 0. Depending on which behavior you want, you may specify

```
np.nanstd(df[cols], ddof=1)
```

Comment: Thank you. I ended up doing something similar